# How can I get only the ratings using IMDbPY/cinemagoer package?

Tags: python, imdbpy

I'm using the Python package cinemagoer to scrape ratings of movies and I want to do it fast. I can retrieve the ratings with my code, but it takes mostly 3 seconds.

Is there an option to get *only* the ratings and not the whole `main` infoset? My thoughts are, that I rewrite my code to something like `ia.get_movie(movie, info=['main']['rating']` but it does not work.

```
import time
from imdb import Cinemagoer

ia = Cinemagoer()

the_matrix = ia.get_movie('0133093', info=['main'])
print('rating is', the_matrix.get('rating'))
```

Comment: Maybe you should try the raw IMDB api. Or if its easier try downloading the rating's file from IMDB S3 database [here is the link](https://cinemagoer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/s3.html). If that is slow or insufficient there is also TMDB, or some csv's on the internet.